# SonarLint Intellij finds no issues in connected mode

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarlint

I have activated the connected mode in the configuration panel. Our SonarQube (version 5.6.5) has a default quality profile. In the configuration panel, I have chosen a project, for which there is no explicit defined quality profile. Thus the default profile is activated. The SonarQube finds issues for this project. However, the SonarLint finds nothing. I have deactivated the connected mode. Then it finds some issues.

Could it be that the SonarLint does not pick up the default profile correctly?

IntelliJ Idea version 2017.1.2
SonarLint version 2.9.0.1816

Thanks.

Comment: An example: SonarQube reports lines, which are more than 120 chars. SonarLint does not report this issue.

Comment: Is the issue in SonarQube resolved, i.e. marked as won't fix or false positive? If that's the case, it will be hidden in SonarLint.

Comment: No. Issue is not resolved or marked. Actually, I have had just committed my changes and there was a few issues in my changes, which are not reported by my sonarlint.

Comment: What is the rule that is not reported in SonarLint? Third party plugins not developped by SonarSource are not supported by SonarLint, so their rules won't appear in it.

Comment: One rule is the _Check that method/constructor/catch/foreach parameters are final_ By the way, this rule seems to be deprecated but still reported by SonarQube. Another is _Operator Wrap_ like _'&&' should be on a new line_

Comment: It would be useful to have the rule keys to confirm, but those rules appear to come from the CheckStyle plugin. As I explained in my last comment, this plugin is not support by SonarLint and won't be loaded.

Comment: I have checked a few. All seems to be checkstyle or findbug related. Now it makes sense to me. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem and issues are marked as Bugs. They just won't come up on SonarLint IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

I'm running IntelliJ Idea 2017.2 and had a similar issue with the sonarlint plugin version 3.3.

When using 3.2.0 available at https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7973-sonarlint it worked for me. You can download the plugin at the given URL and unpack the archive in your `$HOME/IntelliJIdea<VERSION>/config/plugins` folder.